# How to fix ctrl+f on visual studio code

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

Visual studio code lately has changed the search functionality or it is just in my editor.

Previously when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> I could search in the whole opened document.

But lately, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to do a search, it is automatically enabled, the last on the right option, `**Find in selection(Alt+L)**`.

As I don't have any selection active, it cant find anything, and I need to disable the option each time, in order to search all the document.

I attach a screenshot for clarification.
[image]

Could i disable that option by default?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are using Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio which is what you tagged and mentioned  And thus @Vlad's answer is about Visual Studio.  You should change the tags if you mean Visual Studio Code only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Visual Studio Code, check the setting:

`Editor > Find: Auto Find in Selection`

to `never` or `multiline`.  Did yours get set to `always` somehow?

Comment: I dont know how, but somehow it is enabled on the settings  :
"editor.find.autoFindInSelection": true,
Thanks, it is so iritating. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.6. In my case, it was keyboard-related. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> worked for me.